# Firebase runtime crash

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added the Firebase SDK manually to my project (can't use cocoapods due to configuration issues).

Using the following frameworks:

```
FirebaseCore.framework        
FirebaseInstanceID.framework
Firebasemessageing.framework
```

In the `AppDelegate` I have imported this following:

```
#import "Firebase.h
#import <FirebaseInstanceID/FirebaseInstanceID.h>
#import <FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.h>
```

And then I reference the API:

```
[FIRApp configure];
```

All is fine when I build the project. However as soon as the app hits the `Firebase SDK` API - I am getting the following crash:

**Error message in the console:**

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10553f168'

I have added all the required frameworks I can think of, yet still getting this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you've added the GoogleToolboxForMac library to your project and you've added -ObjC to Other Linker Options in Build Settings.

Comment: Thanks - this was it. However I am now facing another crash, related to the FirebaseSDK.

Comment: but if you add objc flag then you can not compile anymore other library like facebook :( any idea ?

Comment: @loki A hack workaround would be to add an explicit call to [NSData gtm_dataByGzippingData:error:] in unexecuted code so that a reference is visible and it doesn't get discarded by the linker.

Comment: thanks paul, however i found another way more simple: use -force_load instead of -ObjC

Comment: @Tander, How you added GoogleToolboxForMac manually, i am getting <launch.h> not found error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to add it under link libraries

Comment: I am getting this-https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac, i am not getting library framework. You have any link for framework?